# Swift WKWebView long press does not show UIMenuItem at once

Tags: swift, safari, google-apps, uimenucontroller, long-press

*Is it able to show UIMenuController at first long press?*

while making web browser using WKWebView in Swift,

somethimes long press doesn't show UIMenuController.

case is just like this.

1. long press the word
2. tap other place of the webView
3. long press the same word again(UIMenuController is showing)
4. tap address bar(all words are selected)
5. tap address bar again(address shows UIMenuController)
6. tap opacity or touch cancel btn - address bar closed
7. long press the original word again.

in this sequence after 7. UIMenuItem should show at first long press,

but UIMenuController shows after second long press.

And, sometimes when UiMenuController shows, tap other place doesn't hide UIMenuController.

this problem happens in iOS google app, safari app

Is it able to show UIMenuController at first long press?